# Show/hide an image works only on IE

Tags: javascript

I have that JavaScript code:

```
  var state = 'hidden';
    function Show_Picture() 
    {
        if (state == 'visible') 
            state = 'hidden';
        else 
            state = 'visible';
        document.getElementById('loader').style.visibility = state;
    }
```

'loader' is the

```
<img alt="" id="loader" src="file:///D:/ajax-loader.gif"/>
```

Why that code doesn't work on FF ? Ont the IE it works OK.

Here's the code:
http://pastebin.com/m38aa1847

Comment: What about it doesn't work on Firefox?

Comment: When are you executing this function?  Are you doing it on load?  If so, is the image actually rendered on the page before this is run?  Do you get a JS error on FF?

Comment: Is that the only image element with the "id" value "loader"?

Comment: [Matchu]: I mean the 'loader' image is still hidden. [Simon]: The code is executed whe the button is pressed. [Pointy]: Yes

Comment: Install the Webdeveloper Toolbar Add-on for Firefox, it includes JS debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually can't reproduce your bug.  I copy-pasted your code from pastebin and ran it on FF 3.5.6 - the only thing I changed was the image source to a local image of my own.

Are you trying to debug it on FF at all?  Try running it with Firebug open and see if any errors are reported.

Test the response code of the image request, too. Perhaps it's the `file://` protocol that isn't working correctly.

### EDIT

Yup - just tested it.  When I changed the image's `src` to a fully-qualified local path (i.e., one with `file://`) it doesn't show up in Firefox. Your Javascript works fine - just change the image path.

Answer (score 0):

Use a framework. They take care of all this cross-browser business for you.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.6.0.3/prototype.js"></script>

<script>
function Show_Picture() {
    $('loader').toggle()
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

var state = 'hidden';

```
function Show_Picture() 

{

    if (state == '') 

        state = 'hidden';

    else 

        state = '';

    document.getElementById('loader').style.visibility = state;

}
```